# Scikit-Learn : Error on K-nn Crossvalidation (the least populated class ...)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, knn

I'm trying to use Knn on a sample of leaf features.
there are  990 row for 194 columns.
The second columns is fill with the tree name where leaf come from, it will be the label.

```
from sklearn import model_selection 
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn import neighbors, metrics

X = data.iloc[:, 2: 194]
y = data.iloc[:,1]
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
y = labelencoder.fit_transform(y)

#separate train and test data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = \
model_selection.train_test_split(X, y , test_size=0.3)

std_scale = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
X_train_std = std_scale.transform(X_train)
X_test_std = std_scale.transform(X_test)

param_grid = {'n_neighbors':[3,5,7,9,11,13,15]}
score = 'accuracy'
clf = model_selection.GridSearchCV(neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(),
param_grid, cv=5, scoring=score)
#here i got the following error

clf.fit(X_train_std, y_train)
```

> C:\Users\chrys\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection_split.py:581: Warning: The least populated class in y has only 4 members, which is too few. The minimum number of groups for any class cannot be less than n_splits=5.
>     % (min_groups, self.n_splits)), Warning)

I got that when "cv" >4, "cv" is how many part we have during the crossvalidation.
I don't understand because my sample should be widely big enough for being divided by even 10.

Here the link of the sample :
[leaf-sample](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/static.oc-static.com/prod/courses/files/Parcours_data_scientist/entrainez-un-modele-predictif-lineaire/Dataset_feuilles_1.csv)

thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my sample should be widely big enough for being divided by even 10

This is only true when you are using the *entire* data set for you training.  Because you have (correctly) split the data into a test and training set, it is very likely that you have at least one class with less instances than then number of cross validation splits.  Especially for your dataset which has 100 classes with only 10 instances for each class.

You can examine you training set labels using:

```
count = {k:0 for k in set(y)}
for yy in y:
    count[yy] += 1
sorted(count.items(), key=lambda i: i[1])
```

When I ran your code, I had four classes that had less than 5 for the cross validation:

```
[(23, 4),
 (39, 4),
 (68, 4),
 (85, 4),
 (17, 5),
 ...
```